# Getting the winner of a match - the rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.5

In my (League) view I want to list all the matches and mark the match as played, the winning team or the match as a tie.

To know if it is a tie or who the winner is, I have to check the score of each opponent. Where do I do these calculations? view helper?, model scope?

My idea is to have three functions that check per match when i list the matches:
    match.played? -> true / false
    match.tie? -> true / false
    match.winner? -> team_id with the highest score.

Database (postgresql)

Matches

```
id | league_id | date
---+-----------+----------
1  | 1         | 2016-03-21 21:00:00
2  | 1         | 2016-03-22 09:00:00
...
```

Opponents
(score is null if not played)

```
id | match_id | team_id | score
---+----------+---------+--------
1  |  1       |  1      |  0
2  |  1       |  2      |  1
3  |  2       |  3      |  1
4  |  2       |  4      |  1
4  |  3       |  1      |  
4  |  3       |  2      |  
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely on the right path. I would have the methods you suggested on my `Match` model with one exception:

```
match.winner #=> returns the Team object of the winner (or nil).
```

I would then have a view helper that called these methods to determine how to render them. I.e., Has it been played? Was it a tie? Who won.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions scope is a little broad for a definitive answer ;)
Ask 5 developers and you will get 12 different answers.

That said, here is what I would do:
Your idea to implement those instance methods is a good starting point, although I personally do not like "?" methods that do not return a boolean value, in my oppinion it should just be `#winner` and should return the team instance, not the id (I take it there is a "Team" model). You might want to think about a complementary `#loser` method.

Your view could look something like this:

```
<table>
  <% @matches.each_with_index do |match, i| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="match number">
      <%= i + 1 %>
    </td>
    <td class="team-1">
      <%= match.team_1 %>
    </td>
    <td class="team-2">
      <%= match.team_2 %>
    </td>
    <td class="winner">
      <% if match.played? %>
        <!-- this would be a view helper since you have to consider
             the tie situation and we do not want that much logic
             in the view. It would return a string with either the
             teams name or "tie". -->
        <%= winner_of_match match %>
      <% else %>
        N/A
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This is just very basic to give you an idea to build on. For example you might want to get rid of the `if match.played` and do it in your view helper (return "not yet played" or something).